# Pass parameters from the command line in shell

Tags: bash, shell

```
DATE1=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y-%m-%d",localtime(time()- 3600*72);'`

DATE2=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m%d",localtime(time()- 3600*72);'`

DATE3=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m%d",localtime(time()- 3600*48);'`

DATE4=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y/%m/%d",localtime(time()- 3600*48);'`
```

Below is my shell script(test1.sh), in which I need to print four dates and all those four dates should come from above. Meaning I need to pass above those four dates from the command prompt only to the below shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Date1
echo Date2
echo Date3
echo Date4
```

So when I am running the shell script like this- it should get Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4 from the above four dates?

```
sh -x test1.sh Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4
```

Is it possible to do in shell script?

Comment: If your system has GNU date,  `DATE4=$(date -d 'now - 48 hours' "+%Y/%m/%d")` is more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute your first code-block in a shell, then you'll have defined 4 variables with the output of those commands. To access any of those variables, you have to prepend a `$` to the variable name - say, `$DATE1`.

So, for running your script with those parameters, you should run:

```
 bash -x test1.sh $DATE1 $DATE2 $DATE3 $DATE4
```

Pay attention to the `$` and the case-sensitiveness.

Finally, in your script, arguments are received in a family of variables that are called with the number of order of the parameter. So, your first parameter is retrieved by `$1`, the second by `$2`, and so on.

So, your script ends up being:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
echo $4
```

Watch also that you are defining a she-bang that tells the script to be interpreted by `bash`, but your previous invocation was using `sh`. They have lots of compatibilities, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to reference the global argument variables if passing via perl.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" # Date1
echo "$2" # Date2
echo "$3" # Date3
echo "$4" # Date4
```

else you can open a sub-shell using `$()` to return the result

```
> echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
2012-11-20
```